# gh-pages -d build Failure

Tags: javascript, github-pages

After adding all the pre_Deploy,Deploy, homepage I am still getting error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEqN6.png)

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://rijuoddusual1999.github.io/simpleparallax",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

I tried multiple times ended with a failure, I want this to work already running late

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the build folder to your own build folder which differs in different project setups. In your case, assuming that `dist` is your build folder, change the scripts to:

```bash
"predeploy": "npm run dist",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
```